# Why reading file line by line takes more memory?

Tags: go, memory-management

I tried to read a large file in this format:

```
a string key, 200 values separated by comma
```

And write it to a map.

I wrote this code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "unsafe"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("file_address.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    mp := make(map[string]float32)
    var total_size int64 = 0
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var counter int64 = 0

    for scanner.Scan() {
        counter++
        sliced := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
        mp[sliced[0]] = 2.2
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("loaded: %d. Took %d Mb of memory.", counter, total_size/1024.0/1024.0)
    fmt.Println("Loading finished. Now waiting...")

    var ms runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms)

    fmt.Printf("\n")
    fmt.Printf("Alloc: %d MB, TotalAlloc: %d MB, Sys: %d MB\n",
        ms.Alloc/1024/1024, ms.TotalAlloc/1024/1024, ms.Sys/1024/1024)
    fmt.Printf("Mallocs: %d, Frees: %d\n",
        ms.Mallocs, ms.Frees)
    fmt.Printf("HeapAlloc: %d MB, HeapSys: %d MB, HeapIdle: %d MB\n",
        ms.HeapAlloc/1024/1024, ms.HeapSys/1024/1024, ms.HeapIdle/1024/1024)
    fmt.Printf("HeapObjects: %d\n", ms.HeapObjects)
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}
```

Here is the output:

```
loaded: 544594. Took 8 Mb of memory.Loading finished. Now waiting...

Alloc: 2667 MB, TotalAlloc: 3973 MB, Sys: 2831 MB
Mallocs: 1108463, Frees: 401665
HeapAlloc: 2667 MB, HeapSys: 2687 MB, HeapIdle: 11 MB
HeapObjects: 706798

Done!
```

Although keys only take around 8Mb, the program takes about 2.7Gb of memory! It seems that `sliced` is never removed from heap. I tried setting `sliced=nil` at the end of `for`, but it didn't help. I have read that if I load the whole file in memory and then split it, I can avoid this problem, but I have to read the file line-by-line, because I don't have enough memory to load some of the larger files.

Why is the memory is occupied? How can I free it after processing each line?

Comment: you can search for `tri color algorithm golang gc` to get more details

Comment: You could use pprof to see exactly where memory allocations are coming from. Profiling an application is a useful skill and this could be a good exercise to learn it.

Comment: @mh-cbon turned out it wasn't because of gc not working. The problem was I still kept a reference to each line of file by keeping `sliced[0]` as the map key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem! I slice each line of the large file. The returned `[]string` is a slice, containing the sub-strings of the original string(line of file). Now the problem is, each sub-string is not a new string. Is is merely a `slice`, which keeps a reference to the un-sliced string(line of file!). I keep the `sliced[0]` for each line, hence, I keep the reference to each line of file. The garbage collector wont touch the read line because I still have reference to it. Technically I read and keep all lines of the file in memory.

The solution is to copy the part I want(`sliced[0]`), to a new string, effectively losing the reference to the whole line. I have done it this way:

```
    sliced := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
    key_rune_arr := []rune(sliced[0])
    key := string(key_rune_arr) // now key is a copy of sliced[0] without reference to line
    mp[key] = 2.2 //instead of mp[sliced[0]] = 2.2
```

The program now becomes:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "unsafe"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("file_address.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    mp := make(map[string]float32)
    var total_size int64 = 0
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var counter int64 = 0

    for scanner.Scan() {
        counter++
        sliced := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
        key_rune_arr := []rune(sliced[0])
        key := string(key_rune_arr) // now key is a copy of sliced[0] without reference to line
        mp[key] = 2.2 //instead of mp[sliced[0]] = 2.2
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("loaded: %d. Took %d Mb of memory.", counter, total_size/1024.0/1024.0)
    fmt.Println("Loading finished. Now waiting...")

    var ms runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms)

    fmt.Printf("\n")
    fmt.Printf("Alloc: %d MB, TotalAlloc: %d MB, Sys: %d MB\n",
        ms.Alloc/1024/1024, ms.TotalAlloc/1024/1024, ms.Sys/1024/1024)
    fmt.Printf("Mallocs: %d, Frees: %d\n",
        ms.Mallocs, ms.Frees)
    fmt.Printf("HeapAlloc: %d MB, HeapSys: %d MB, HeapIdle: %d MB\n",
        ms.HeapAlloc/1024/1024, ms.HeapSys/1024/1024, ms.HeapIdle/1024/1024)
    fmt.Printf("HeapObjects: %d\n", ms.HeapObjects)
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}
```

The result is as I wanted it to be:

```
loaded: 544594. Took 8 Mb id memory.Loading finished. Now waiting...

Alloc: 94 MB, TotalAlloc: 3986 MB, Sys: 135 MB
Mallocs: 1653590, Frees: 1108129
HeapAlloc: 94 MB, HeapSys: 127 MB, HeapIdle: 32 MB
HeapObjects: 545461

Done!
```

Answer (score 4):

For efficient CPU and memory usage,

```
key := string(bytes.SplitN(scanner.Bytes(), []byte(","), 2)[0])
mp[key] = 2.2
```